# How do you create a shallow copy of an Array in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

```
var a:Array = ["a","b","c"];

var b:Array;

/* insert code here to copy 'a' and assign it to 'b'*/
```

Comment: You're in luck: shallow copy is trivial, it's deep copy that requires a big chunk of code thanks to Arrays not being typed collections :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taken from the As3 reference guide:

> The Array class has no built-in
>   method for making copies of arrays.
>   You can create a shallow copy of an
>   array by calling either the concat()
>   or slice() methods with no arguments.
>   In a shallow copy, if the original
>   array has elements that are objects,
>   only the references to the objects are
>   copied rather than the objects
>   themselves. The copy points to the
>   same objects as the original does. Any
>   changes made to the objects are
>   reflected in both arrays.

Concat would be the way to go if you choose between concat and slice since concat is faster in terms of performance.

Read more about the subject here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html

To clarify:

```
    private function shallowCopy():void{
        var a:Array = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];
        var b:Array = a.concat(); 

        trace("Shallow copy:");
        trace("Before delete: " + a);
        trace("Before delete: " + b);
        delete a[0];
        trace("After delete: " + a);
        trace("After delete: " + b);            
    }
```

Comment: I keep forgetting that AS3 is a superset of Javascript. Thanks

Comment: Your deepCopy() function is not doing a deep copy, you're copying nothing but the reference to the Array itself  (i.e. it's not an array copy at all). In AS3, a deep copy requires looping over the contents of the array, and manually constructing new objects of matching type and then copying their values. var b:Array = a; just creates a new reference to your Array a.

Comment: Then I most have misunderstood the concept. I'll remove the code :) Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: A deep copy would be one where any objects referenced in the array get cloned and the clones are referenced at the corresponding point in the new array. Because objects can--and usually do--have references to other objects, you can see how this could be fixed depth, or fully recursive. But it's a nastier problem than recursively cloning everything, because you might have two objects in your array (A and B) both referencing C. When you do the deep copy, Aclone and Bclone should reference the same Cclone, not two new clones of C. That's why I said to Gareth that he's asked the easy question :-)

Comment: You can find an implementation of a deep copy [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html)

Answer (score 8):

The line in question:

```
var b:Array = a.concat();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array contains just string or number values, it's enough to make a "shallow" copy, as described by Adam and rzetterberg.

If the array contains other arrays or objects/class instances, etc. then you should make a deep copy if you need all of the objects inside to be unique as well and not just references. You can achieve that with:

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
ba.writeObject(a); // Copy the original array (a) into a ByteArray instance
ba.position = 0; // Put the cursor at the beginning of the ByteArray to read it
var b:Array = ba.readObject(); // Store a copy of the array in the destination array (b)
ba.clear(); // Free memory
```

This is also useful for copying Objects, which don't have any concat or splice methods.